# Scripting Safari won't work on a specific iMac

Tags: text, safari, tabs, applescript

Hy,

To automate access to certain sites I need to know the content of the pages displayed. For that I use this code (extract of the complete script):

```
tell application "Safari"
    activate
    set res to text of the first tab of the first window
end tell
```

My problem: if this program works correctly on some iMac, it does not work on one in particular.

On this computer, it returns to me either an empty chain or a "missing value".
Of course the system, Safari and Applescript versions are the same on the different iMac.

Do you have any idea what can cause this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Does the first Safari window contain always the same web sites or are there different sites open?

Asking the `first tab` does not work if the Safari window contains only a single web site. However, using the `current tab` does work in any case:

```
set res to text of current tab of first window
```

Answer (score 0):

Hy,

Thank you for your reply !

Two things :

- without any explanation, my script works now on the relevant iMac!
  Yet I tried a lot of things (reboot, …).
- it seems that `set res to text of first tab of first window` 
  works on Safari, even if there is only one website on the page. But thanks for the idea of "current tab", cleaner!